# Calling a superclass function for a class with multiple superclass

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance

I have a class that extends two classes, one of them including threading.Thread. How do I call the start method of the threading.Thread from the subclass?

```
class Poller(threading.Thread, <some other class>):
    """
    poller code 
    """
    def start():
        return super(Poller,self).start()
```

I want to start thread class' start function. This is not going to work right?

Comment: It should work (except that you've forgotten to include `self` as a parameter). Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to pass the self as parameter?

Comment: Any function belonging to a class, unless it's a static method has to have self as the first parameter. When the function is called on the object of the class, the reference of this object binds to this first self parameter. So, you don't pass self from the call, it's done for you by python. This is useful in context of inheritance where self could mean, that class' object reference or one of the child class' object reference.

Comment: "Can you please explain why I need to pass the self as parameter?" Because if you don't, it won't work...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be sure to just call Thread's start you can do:

```
def start(self):
    threading.Thread.start(self)
```

Note that this will avoid the other base class's start method and may not be what you want

Answer (score -1):

start() method missing "self" keyword

```
class Poller(threading.Thread, <some other class>):
    """
    poller code 
    """
    def start(self):
        return super(Poller,self).start()
```

Comment: threading.Thread refers to the class Thread in the module threading